# HTML/CSS full width issue with scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Here is the snippet:

```css
#bar {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

#content {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="content">1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
</div>
```

When I put 2 div ("bar", "content") inside a parent div and I set parent div to fixed width and height and overflow is auto to enable scroll bar. Then set "content"'s width larger than its' parent' width and "bar"'s width to 100%.
It turn out "bar"'s width will be same as its' parent, not its' sibling "content".
Thus when you scroll it, "bar" will scroll together instead of keep there...

Is any solution we can keep "bar" on the top or set it to 100% width as its' sibling "content" div?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can wrap the *content in a scroll wrapper*, instead of the outer box.
See code below:

```css
#parentBox {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
}
#bar {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
#content {
  width: 1000px;
}
.scrollWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentBox">
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div class="scrollWrapper">
    <div id="content">1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, using a little bit of hackery.  Since this is a display-only div you might as well take it out of the document flow.  As a bonus, this makes your HTML more semantically correct!

What we're doing is setting your content to have a width that's known to the browser (using the `display:inline-block;` property – Blocks have layout, inlines don't).  Then, we create a pseudo `:before` element to show your header and let it fill the layout that we just gave to your content.

```css
#content:before {
  height: 30px;
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  display:block;
}
#content {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
  <div id="content">1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user10110 – Glad to hear it!  You marked the other answer, though.  Did you mean to comment on their response?